# SQL Server trigger is preventing row from being inserted into the database and doesn't execute stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I'm trying to get a trigger to fire after a row has been inserted into a database. The application works fine with the trigger disabled, but when it is enabled, the row is never inserted into the database (from the application) and the trigger doesn't fire the stored procedure.

Shouldn't `AFTER INSERT` fire the trigger `AFTER` the database table row has been inserted?

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trSendException]
ON  [dbo].[Logs]   
AFTER INSERT  
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    EXEC dbo.EmailExceptionAlerts
END
```

I need the trigger to execute the stored procedure after a row has been inserted into my database from the application.

Comment: Based on that your SP must have an error in it. If you manually insert a row from SSMS do you get any error messages?

Comment: I believe if something happens in the TRIGGER code to cause a rollback (such as a fatal error), the INSERT will be rolled back as well.

Comment: you could add a TRY CATCH block in your trigger to see if you are getting an exception or not.  Or, comment out the Email proc to see if at least the insert is completing successfully.

Comment: I manually inserted a row and did not get an error, the triggered fired and executed the stored procedure. So, I'm assuming that means there is a problem with the stored procedure that initially inserts the row? The strange thing is it works fine if I disable the trigger. I'll take a closer look at my stored proc.

Comment: Sounds to me like you have an anti-pattern in your application which I call try/squelch. That is a try/catch block that swallows the exception instead of letting the application know something went wrong.

Comment: Sean you are correct. I used a try catch block in the method within my application that's executing the initial stored procedure to insert a row and getting this exception: The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'sp_send_dbmail', database 'msdb', schema 'dbo'. I've seen that execute permission error before but not on a system stored procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a try catch block in the method within my application that's executing the initial stored procedure (as suggested) to insert a row and got the exception: The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'sp_send_dbmail', database 'msdb', schema 'dbo'. I then granted access to msdb for the user and checked the option for DatabaseMailUserRole under user mappings for the user's login properties. It's now working as it should. Thanks!

Comment: umm - maybe you should also fix the error handling so that it doesn't eat the error?